# How to conditionally select records from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Friends,

I have a SQL problem I could use help on. I'm working with SQL Server 2008.

The use case is the following. We have a system where users watch videos, and each time a user watches a video, we record that activity. We capture three properties each time; assetid (an asset is a video), customerid, and status.

A record can have three different statuses; 'completion', 'playing', and 'start'.

The person who wrote this part of the system is not a developer, and instead of of updating the status of an existing record, inserts a new duplicate record each time a user watches a video. Therefore we have thousands of duplicate records. Here is a sample dataset

[image]

The problem I need to solve is to select a record by assetid, customerid, and status. I need to choose a record that has a status of 'completion' if it exists.

If a record has a status of 'playing', but no record with the same assetid and customerid with a status of 'completion' exists, then choose that record.

If a record has a status of 'start', but no record with the same assetid and customerid with a status of either 'completion' or 'playing' exists, then choose that record.

Here is sample code where I tried to use a CASE statement to solve the problem. I also tried another case statement with a NOT IN subquery, but without success.

```
INSERT INTO #ViewTime (AssetID, CustomerID, ViewTime)
SELECT 
     tt.customerid, tt.assetId, tt.assetstatus, 
    CASE WHEN 
        tt.AssetStatus = 'COMPLETION' 
    AND 
        ISNUMERIC(timeposition) = 1 
    THEN 
        CONVERT(Numeric(18,3), timePosition)
    WHEN 
        tt.AssetStatus = 'PLAYING'
    AND 
        ISNUMERIC(timeposition) = 1 
    THEN 
        CONVERT(Numeric(18,3), timePosition)
    WHEN 
        tt.AssetStatus = 'START' 
    AND 
        ISNUMERIC(timeposition) = 1 
    THEN 
        CONVERT(Numeric(18,3), timePosition)
    ELSE null
    END AS ViewTime
FROM 
    TableAssetTracking tt
    inner join TableAssets ta
    on tt.AssetID = ta.AssetID
WHERE 
    tt.timePosition is not null
AND 
    AssetBuffering is null
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Derek

Comment: Instead of an image for sample data how about some ddl and consumable data? Also an explanation of what you expect as output would help considerably. You might consider this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, this question might be better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @John On DBA they would just consider this base SQL and stay on SE

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sean. I will add some DDL and consumable data. That is a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I need to solve is to select a record by assetid, customerid, and status.

I need to choose a record that has a status of 'completion' if it exists.

```
select distinct assetID, CustomerID  
  from table 
 where status = 'complete'
```

If a record has a status of 'playing', but no record with the same assetid and customerid with a status of 'completion' exists, then choose that record.

```
select assetID, CustomerID  
  from table 
 where status = 'playing'
except
select assetID, CustomerID  
  from table 
 where status = 'complete'
```

If a record has a status of 'start', but no record with the same assetid and customerid with a status of either 'completion' or 'playing' exists, then choose that record.

```
select assetID, CustomerID  
  from table 
 where status = 'start'
except
select assetID, CustomerID  
  from table 
 where status in ('complete', 'playing')
```

The above is not going to give you ViewTime that I see in the example
It was not in the requirements statement

```
select * 
from 
(  select assetID, CustomerID, status, ViewTime 
        , row_number() over (partition by assetID, CustomerID order by status, ViewTime desc) as rn
     from table 
    where status in ('complete', 'playing', 'start') 
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: Down vote would you care to share what it lacking in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to do this.   Here is one.

I am going to use psuedocode because the tables in your sample code don't match the description in your question.   You will have to adapt this technique to your tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.AssetId, t.CustomerId, (
  SELECT TOP 1 Status
  FROM MyTable t1
  WHERE t1.AssetId=t.AssetId
  AND t1.CustomerId=t.CustomerId
  ORDER BY CASE t1.Status
   WHEN 'Completion' THEN 0
   WHEN 'Playing' THEN 1
   WHEN 'Started' THEN 2
   ELSE 3
  END ASC
) AS Status
FROM MyTable t
```

Comment: You people are the best. All of the solutions were great. I used the solution suggested by Paparazzi, and it solved my problem. Thanks much to everyone.

Comment: Tab, would you mind clarifying your solution for me? I want to understand it fully. I get the ORDER BY CASE. The part I'm unclear on is the subquery with the WHERE statement. Can you explain the need for MyTable t1, and the WHERE statement of t1.AssetId=t.AssetId? Thanks much.

Comment: The WHERE statement is needed to correlate the subquery to the main query, to make sure you are only look at Status for the current row of the main query.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in order to show you a broad way of looking at your data. You want to REALLY identify the last record that was inserted into your table for each person and video. So we get the last one, and then get the status for that record.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#lastRecord') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #lastRecord

    SELECT
        max(trackingassetdatecreated) dt,
        assetid,
        customerid,
    INTO #lastRecord
    FROM 
        TableAssetTracking
    GROUP BY
        assetid,
        customerid

    SELECT
        t.assetstatus,
        lr.*
    FROM
        TableAssetTracking t
    INNER JOIN
        #lastRecord lr on
            lr.trackingassetdatecreated = t.trackingassetdatecreated
            and lr.assetid = t.assetid
            and lr.customerid = t.customerid
```